# On the back foot

Tags: word-usage, american-english

Do you use the phrase " on the back foot" in America?
On the back foot= at a disadvantage, on the defensive,  outmanoeuvred or outclassed ( Collins)

Comment: It's not a common idiom in the US -- in fact, I'd guess that most people don't know it's meaning but can sort of decode it from context.

Comment: The notion seems to be somewhat similar to the U.S. English term "caught flat-footed"—meaning unready, unprepared, off-guard, at a tactical disadvantage, etc.

Comment: @SvenYargs That and "put one's best foot forward".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I (native speaker of American English) have *heard of* this expression, but I don't use it and don't commonly hear it used by US speakers. While the phrase does show up in print in the US, it generally isn't used in the idiomatic British sense.

That is, [the top hits in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on%20the%20back%20foot%22&lr=lang_en&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ1quWyIzXAhWX14MKHboTArQQpwUIHg&biw=1344&bih=735&dpr=1.25) that are not clearly British (not about the game of cricket, e.g.) are using the phrase in its literal sense: in two different books describing [dance steps](https://books.google.com/books?id=ryx8CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT31&dq=%22on%20the%20back%20foot%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ1quWyIzXAhWX14MKHboTArQQ6AEILTAB) ([more about dancing here](https://books.google.com/books?id=WTtAAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA7&dq=%22on%20the%20back%20foot%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ1quWyIzXAhWX14MKHboTArQQ6AEIOTAD)), one about [weight balance during wind-surfing](https://books.google.com/books?id=T2fvZKaTWLsC&pg=PP53&dq=%22on%20the%20back%20foot%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ1quWyIzXAhWX14MKHboTArQQ6AEIRTAF), another about [how to animate a person walking](https://books.google.com/books?id=VmXoE5WlUUQC&pg=PA70&dq=%22on%20the%20back%20foot%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ1quWyIzXAhWX14MKHboTArQQ6AEIUTAH), etc.

Limiting the [Google Books search to books from the 21st century and ordering with most recent first](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on%20the%20back%20foot%22&lr=lang_en&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099,sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXsL2LyozXAhVE_IMKHQ3BA68QpwUIHg&biw=1344&bih=735&dpr=1.25) gives a similar result: the first two pages of results are by British (and Australian) authors with a few scattered examples of the literal usage of the term by American authors. This is not to say that the phrase is never used with this sense by Americans, just that it is not common or widespread.

Answer (score 2):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_the_back_foot) attributes the expression 'on the back foot' to cricket, the batsman moving his weight on to his back foot as he makes a defensive manoeuvre with the bat rather than a forward stroke to the ball. So, yes a BrE origin but, as demonstrated in Josh's answer, clearly now used in AmE.

This surprised me as I was expecting a boxing origin. But the boxing equivalent appears to be 'on the 'ropes'.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on-the-ropes)

Comment: It's not exactly true that a batsman on the back foot is on the defensive. The forward defensive is the first shot we teach, and some attacking shots, like the hook, are played off the back foot. The disadvantage of being on the back foot is that if the batsman unexpectedly has to play a defensive shot, e.g. if the ball does not bounce as high as he expected, he has fewer options, and those he has are riskier.

Comment: @RupertMorrish Brings back school memories - forward defensive and backward defensive.